# Where is the sticky post option?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, sticky-post

So I finally need to include sticky posts in a theme but it looks like the feature is gone. When I create a new post, and click "visiblity", the sticky option is missing. I checked a couple other sites sites (and the defualt twenty fourteen theme) and it looks like they're all gone. Is that an option I need to enable in my theme now?

Also - I see that custom post types can not be "stickied" is there a plugin which will give me that feature?

[image]

Comment: Make sure "Public" is selected. Also, I believe only Posts can be made sticky. Are you looking on Posts (capital P)? I can still see it just fine.

Comment: I added an image of what Im seeing. Thats on teh twenty fourteen theme, using the standard "Post" post type.

Comment: Are all plugins disabled too?

Comment: I got it, looks like it was a capability issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the problem is with wordpress capabilities. One of them, likely the "edit_posts" capability is what gives uses access to the sticky post feature.

Im not sure which one, I just gave my user role ALL capabilities and it began working again.